# Authenticate asp.net users after Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, forms-authentication

I have an application that will only be used by employees in my organisation. This will be restricted with Azure Active Directory, so only users within the  domain will be able to access the site.

After that I need to add further security so only certain employees access the site. I have a (MS) SQL table with all the usernames that are eligible.

The username will be lifted directly from the Azure Active Directory by using

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

(this has been tested and returns the correct syntax and string etc)

My first thought was to use forms authentication, then on the "login.aspx" Page_Load, check against the SQL table and if exists then continue into the site

`FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, true)`

And if not then load the login.aspx page with a form to fill out to request access.

Question is, is this the best way to do it, without re-writing the entire solution.

- I have multiple aspx pages inside the site so don't want to add the "check" to each page.
- The users won't need to enter a password.

EDIT 25/12/17 Thanks to @juunas and @PeterBons - this is what i have got in my Page_load event of my login form, then web.config handles the forms authenication.
Can anyone see any MASSIVE error or flaw in security?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isAuthenticated = false;
    string username = User.Identity.Name.ToLower().Trim();

    string firstname = "";
    string surname = "";
    string jobrole = "";
    string userlevel = "";

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureSQL"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(constr);
    string query = "Select * from Usernames";
    string querywriteTime = "update [usernames] set [last log in] = @date where username = @username";
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(querywriteTime, cnn);
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, cnn);
    cnn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        if (rdr[0].ToString().ToLower().Trim() == username)
        {
            firstname = rdr[1].ToString().Trim();
            surname = rdr[2].ToString().Trim();
            jobrole = rdr[4].ToString().Trim();
            userlevel = rdr[5].ToString().Trim();
            isAuthenticated = true;
        }

    }
    cnn.Close();

    if (isAuthenticated)
    {
        string str = firstname + "/" + surname + "/" + jobrole+"/"+userlevel;
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
        cnn.Open();
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn.Close();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(str, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-aspnetwebapp-v1) already? Might be of help.

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons, looked through the Docs, but can't seem to find where to pass or check against the SQL "username" table to see which users should be allowed in. The Azure AD will authenticate all employees in my organisation, but I need to restrict it to certain users.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the app to *require user assignment* in the Azure portal.

1. Go to portal.azure.com
2. Find Azure Active Directory
3. Go to Enterprise applications
4. Go to All applications
5. Find your app
6. Go to Properties
7. Tick **User assignment required?**

Now you can go to the Users and groups tab and select who has access.